# Use python to loop over two lists, using one as an index to a list of lists, and the other as a value to append

Tags: python, list, zip, append

I am having some trouble getting expected results out of the zip command. Cases 1-3 make sense, but in cases 4 and 5 (which I assume are equivalent?) I expect the results to be [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']], but instead the entirety of the second list is appended to each sublist of the list of lists I initialize.

Case 1:

```
>>> for a in zip([1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d']):
...     print a

(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(4, 'd')
```

Case 2:

```
>>> for (a,b) in zip([1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d']):
...     print a,b
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Case 3:

```
>>> temp = [[]] * 4
>>> for (a,b) in zip([0,1,2,3],['a','b','c','d']):
...     temp[a] = b
... 
>>> temp
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Case 4:

```
>>> temp = [[]] * 4
>>> for (a,b) in zip([0,1,2,3],['a','b','c','d']):
...     temp[a].append(b)
... 
>>> temp
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Case 5:

```
>>> temp = [[]] * 4
>>> for a,b in zip([0,1,2,3],['a','b','c','d']):
...     temp[a].append(b)
... 
>>> temp
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into the way Python deals with variable names and references. It can be confusing if you have worked with C-style languages before, but makes a lot of sense if you don't think that way!

Python has "things" and "names for things". For example, `x` is a name, `[]` is a thing, and `x=[]` assigns the name `x` to the thing `[]`.

The list multiplication syntax is a bit confusing with regards to names and things. Let's expand it out to see how it works:

> ```
> name = [x]*4
> ```
>
> is the same as
>
> ```
> _temp = x
> name = [_temp, _temp, _temp, _temp]
> ```

With that in mind, the following code should make sense:

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = [x]*4
>>> y[0].append(1)
>>> y
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Why? Well, when you write `y=[x]*4]` you make a list of four names. But those are all names for the *same* thing! If you `.append(1)` to the object named by the first name, you change the object that all the names, well, name.

Now, just as before,

> ```
> name = [[]]*4
> ```
>
> is the same as
>
> ```
> _temp = []
> name = [_temp, _temp, _temp, _temp]
> ```

You haven't explicitly created a new name. But you have done so *implicitly*! You only call `[]` once, so you only make one new list. You then make a list of four names, each of the new empty list you just made. So it should come as no surprise that all the names name the same thing!

---

How to fix this, you say? Well, you need to call `[]` once for *each* new list that you want. To do that, use a list comprehension:

```
[[] for _ in range(4)]
```

Note that `_` is just another name, although it is conventionally used for things you don't care about.

Comment: Thank you, that was a really excellent answer! It makes great sense now.

Answer (score 3):

`[[]] * 4` creates a list of references to the single object:

```
>>> l = [[]] * 4
>>> l
[[], [], [], []]
>>> l[0].append(1)
>>> l
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Try `[[] for _ in range(4)]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = [[]] * 4
```

This creates a list that contains four references *to the same list object*. You only have one "sublist" that is contained four time in the "master list". It's the same situation as in this example:

```
>>> ls = []
>>> tmp = [ls, ls, ls, ls]
>>> ls.append(1)
>>> tmp
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

You probably wanted to use separate list objects for your list elements. Such a list could for example be created this way:

```
tmp = [[] for _ in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you create temp = [[]]*4, you create a list with 4 references to the same (empty) list.